# Upper Limits in Combination of like objects

Tags: combinatorics, combinations

I know that the number of ways of grouping n like objects into r groups is given by C(n+r-1,r-1)
But when it has been specified for some particular groups,say 1 or 2, that it can't contain more than 'k' objects
How do you calculate that?

Comment: You have to subtract the number of cases in which there at least $k + 1$ objects in the excluded group.  If you place $k + 1$ objects in that group, you are left with $n - (k + 1)$ identical objects to distribute to $r$ recipients.

Comment: Thanks a lot Sir